# What is meant by structure of vector space and how a function can be used to compare between them?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, soft-question

Can somebody please explain what structure of vector space mean and how can we use function here.

"The question now is how one can determine whether or not two given vector spaces have the 'same' structure as vector spaces, or can be identified as the same vector space. To answer the question,one has to compare them first as sets, and then see whether their arithmetic rules are the same or not. A usual way of comparing two sets is to define a function between them"

If possible please also give me real time use of this property.

Comment: for example, $\mathbb C$ has the same structure as $\mathbb R^2$ as a vector space over $\mathbb R$, with the correspondence $x+iy\mapsto(x,y)$ that is compatible with addition and scalar multiplication, so any results we have about $\mathbb C$ as a vector space over $\mathbb R$ carry over to $\mathbb R^2$ and vice versa

Comment: If it helps, this quote is very poorly written and suggests to me someone who has very little experience or ability in conveying meaningful and unambiguous "dumbed-down" statements for exposition purposes. For example, "this question" would NOT naturally occur to someone until **after** one has seen examples that can then be referred to (e.g. complex numbers via a certain collection of $2 \times 2$ matrices). And although I know what "compare them as sets" is intended to mean (cardinality), I'm sure the intended reader doesn't. Also, the intended reader **(continued)**

Comment: is probably not going to know what it means for arithmetic rules to be the same until **after** one understands the idea being described (or has seen several examples). And finally (for these comments, at least), saying "a usual way of comparing two sets is ..." is especially opaque unless someone has already seen this idea in many other contexts (and probably this is not the case, given this is linear algebra, which is typically studied before groups, rings, metric spaces, topological spaces, etc.). Maybe more context was given in the book you got this, but if not, I stand by my criticism.